# SQL - invalid identifier (not letting me create a foreign key constraint)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently creating a database that models something like iTunes and am having trouble creating my foreign key constraints.

Here's my song table.

```
CREATE TABLE Song 
( 
    SongName varchar2(30) NOT NULL, 
    Remixer varchar2(50) NULL,
    TrackID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Genre varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
    ReleaseDate date NOT NULL,
    Bpm int NOT NULL,
    Key varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
    ArtistID int NOT NULL,
    LabelID int NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT artist_artistID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artist(ArtistID),
    CONSTRAINT label_labelID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (LabelID) REFERENCES Label(LabelID)
);
```

This runs fine but when I go to create my marketplace table it gives me this:

> ORA-00904: "TRACKID": invalid identifier

Here is my marketplace CREATE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Marketplace
(
    MarketplaceID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MarketplaceName varchar2(30) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT track_trackID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (TrackID) REFERENCES Song(TrackID),
    CONSTRAINT artist_artistID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (ArtistID) REFERENCES Artist(ArtistID),
    CONSTRAINT label_labelID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (LabelID) REFERENCES Label(LabelID),
    CONSTRAINT ep_epID_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (EpID) REFERENCES Ep(EpID)
);
```

I also have tables for Artist, Label and EP. Artist and label worked fine but Marketplace and EP didn't work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have to have the TrackID column in the child table too - an FK doesn't create the column.

Answer (score 1):

There is no TrackID column being defined at Marketplace table